# Trick to recognize value of 2's complement number

Tags: digital-logic

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qH4unVtJkE) on YouTube, at [12:04](https://youtu.be/4qH4unVtJkE?feature=shared&t=724), Ben Eater said that the weight of four-bit signed-2's-complement numbers is -8 4 2 1.
For example, to recognize what is the (decimal) value of 1101. We take 2's complement of 1101 = 0011 = (+3) in decimal, therefore 1101 represents -3.
But with a "trick" about the weight, we just calculate -8×1 + 4×1 + 2×0 + 1×1 = -3.

My question is, how can he know that weird "weight" of signed-complement numbers? Is there any mathematical way to prove this "-8 4 2 1"?

Comment: It follows easily from the proof that a number and its two's-complement negative add to ("0000", carry 1).

Comment: I think it's just a matter of opinion which technique is the "trick" and which is the "real" way. They both give the same result after all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a mathematical proof, so I'm not sure whether or not this is something that helps you. But for me it is always helpful to visualize the modulo-arithmetic of fixed-digit number systems in a number circle.

Black numbers outside is just unsigned encoding, green and red in the middle is 2's complement. It is clearly visible what happens during an overflow or when entering negative space. As we encode 1000... as our highest negative number \$ (-2^{N-1}) \$, we have to increase (make it less negative) with every additional bit set.

[image]

Logically this circle is our baseline, this is the behaviour we want in many cases for our signed binary math, because it enables us to use the same standard unsigned arithmetic unit also for signed math. And when evaluting how you can arrive at these encodings for the negative numbers, you happen to discover the method of the 2's complement.

Comment: I was taught 2's complement first year of university. I only learned the formulas and algorithms related to the concept. I thought it was cumbersome and difficult to remember all the details to get it correctly. Years later I come across the statement (paraphrased from memory) "n-bit 2's complement is, exactly like n bit unsigned, just arithmetic modulo 2^n, except half the bit strings change which number they represent" and everything fell into place. Why we weren't taught that from the beginning, I have no idea. I wish more people were.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately quite a few courses, especially at universities, seem to omit some intuitive explanation. Not only in this case of number systems, but in general. I'm very much in favour of offering always some intuitive approach as it just helps to understand what we are doing.

Comment: Can you share the name of the book that you got this number circle from? Thank you so much.

Comment: That exact image is one I have drawn myself (in powerpoint, lol) a few years back. But I saw similar graphics in different books and online resources, although I can't tell you any specific one from the top of my head...

Answer (score 4):

Those are just bits representing a number in binary numeral system so they are powers of two and thus those are the weights in decimal of the binary bits.

It's really not any more complex than say 987 in decimal really means 100*9+10*8+1*7 and the factors are 10^2, 10^1 and 10^0.

So 1101 in binary is 1*2^3+1*2^2+0*2^1+1*2^0. And 2^3 is 8, 2^2 is 4, etc for 2 and 1. For unsigned numbers.

So 4-bit range for unsigned binary numbers is 0000..1111 or 0..15 in decimal, kind of like 4-digit numbers can go from 0000 to 9999.

For the signed numbers, 4-bit range is from -8 to +7, because first bit is sign and the three remaining bits can go from 0 to 7.

If you have say 4 digit decimal code wheel or odometer and you count up from 0000 to 9999 by increasing by one, what comes after 9999? You add one and you would get 10000, but you don't have the fifth digit so you get 0000. Which means, if you decrease 0000 by 1, you should get -1, but it looks like you get 9999. So let's think for a moment what happens if you take 9999 and add 9999? You get 19998 without the leading digit again so 9998. Add 9999 again and you get 9997. Therefore, for all purposes, 9999 must be a code for -1, and 9998 must be a code for -2, because after all, if you add 9998 and 2 you get 0000.

Now, the same works in bits too.
Thus, 1111 must be -1 as if you add one you get 0000. And we already know 0111 is 7. And we know that by adding 7 to some -8 must be -1, and thus, if you take 1000 and add 0111, it must be 1111, so they are known values for -8, 7 and -1.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. The left bit just means that the number is negative.
And the negative numbers go 'backwards':

```
7 (111) is -1 
6 is -2 
5 is -3 
4 is -4
...
```

So you have to substract the value from 2^n:

```
-8 + 7 is -1
-8 + 6 is -2
-8 + 5 is -3
-8 + 4 is -4
...
```

That's why he takes the first bit negative and the rest positive, to make the positive part 'move backwards'.