# Detecting 2's complement overflow

Tags: digital-logic, complement

The method of detecting overflow that I have read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805087/how-is-overflow-detected-in-twos-complement), and have watched in [this](https://youtu.be/nr6b5RjfIGQ?t=248) is comparing Carry-out & Carry-on of MSB (or Carry-out n & Carry-out n-1).
If Carry-out \$\neq\$ Carry-on - Overflow.
If Carry-out = Carry-on - no Overflow.
Is there any way to explain the method of comparison carry flags to find out overflow?

Comment: what do you mean by `is there any way to explain ...?`

Comment: I mean I don't understand that method, how can I understand it ?

Comment: Please think about the weight you found explained in [your other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/681329/228879), and then write down a truth table of all possible carry situations. You might want to add that to this question by [edit]ing it, and tell us what is left to explain.

Comment: are you wanting to understand why the comparison determines an overflow, or are you wanting to know about the xor truth table?

Comment: Yes, the comparison, @old_timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in a two's complement system, there are two ways to detect whether there is an overflow happening. The first one is what you have mentioned, checking whether the carry-out and the carry-in (I prefer to call it in because I think it makes more sense) are the same. This can be easily done by using an XOR gate. **The reason for doing so is that the overflow in a two's complement occurs when the carry into it does not match the carry-out.**  The second one is to check whether the MSB of your two inputs is the same as the sign bit of your result. (It is easy to understand, so I won't explain it here)

This mismatch only contains two cases.

The first one is if there is a carry-in but without the carry-out. That means both of the MSB of the input number are 0, but the result's sign is 1. That means you add two positive numbers but get a negative one. Thus, overflow.

The second case is that if you don't have a carry-in but have a carry-out. That means both of the MSB of the input are 1 and your result's sign bit is 0. That means you add two negative numbers but get a positive one. Obviously, it overflows. So, this is the explanation for why we use the XOR gate to check the MSB's carry-out and carry-in to check overflow.

You may also find this link very useful:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330787/signed-overflow-why-carry-in-and-carry-out-of-msb-should-match#:~:text=Since%20MSB%20is%20the%20sign,non%2Dnegative%2C%20thus%20overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330787/signed-overflow-why-carry-in-and-carry-out-of-msb-should-match#:%7E:text=Since%20MSB%20is%20the%20sign,non%2Dnegative%2C%20thus%20overflow).
Also, this link is also very useful: https://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt

Comment: This is a perfect answer, a comment would have been wrong. This site is not a forum. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and "[answer]". There is a reason that you cannot comment without reputation. ;-)

Comment: Ohhhh, sorry, l am new here. But thanks a lot for your explanation!

Comment: That's why I pointed you to the help pages. Don't you look around before joining a community? That can be a pitfall...